# Accessing $refs in interpolation does not work/causes error (Vue.js 2.x components)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I made the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxgPKJ?editors=1011):

```js
const sidebar = {
  name: "sidebar",
  template: "<p>SIDEBAR</p>",
  data() {
    return {
      active: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      alert("test: " + this.active)
    }
  }
};
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'vue-instance',
  
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Title of the page"
    };
  }, 
  components: {
    sidebar: sidebar,  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{ title }}
  
    <sidebar ref="sidebar1">
    </sidebar>
  
  <button type="button" v-on:click="$refs.sidebar1.test()">Test sidebar</button>
   
<!-- {{ $refs.sidebar1.active }} this causes error! -->
  {{ $refs }}
</div>
```

The commented line causes the error : `"message": "$refs.sidebar1 is undefined",`

So it seems that in the parent component at the time of the rendering the `$refs` collection is empty, but later, when clicking on the button, the `$refs` works fine and can access the component `sidebar1` properly.

Why is it so?
How could one get the interpolation `{{ $refs.sidebar1.active }}` working in the parent component template?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it so? How could one get the interpolation
> `$refs.sidebar1.active` working in the parent component template?

Vue is able to populate refs only when child components are created in parent `render` function and `refs` field is not reactive at all.

When you specify click handler it wraps up in function and executes only when you click the button(as expected), by this time `refs` has been set already(because initial rendering process is over) and there is no error.

Vue docs: [Accessing Child Component Instances](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

As a solution for your example: you can use props to control child from outside and `sync` modifier to allow child to change prop like `v-model`. It will be more readable to extract work with `refs` into some parent function as well:

```js
const sidebar = {
  name: "sidebar",
  template: "<p>SIDEBAR</p>",
  props: ['active'],
  methods: {
    test() {
      alert("test: " + this.active)
    }
  }
};
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'vue-instance',
  
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
      title: "Title of the page"
    };
  }, 
  methods: {
    testChild() {
      this.$refs.sidebar1.test();
    }
  },
  components: {
    sidebar: sidebar,  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{ title }}
  
    <sidebar ref="sidebar1" :active.sync="active">
    </sidebar>
  
  <button type="button" v-on:click="active = !active">Toggle</button>
  <button type="button" v-on:click="testChild">Test child</button>
   
<!--      {{ $refs.sidebar1.active }} this causes error! -->
  {{ active }}
</div>
```

Comment: The key info for me was : `$refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within templates or computed properties.`
Thanks a lot for the Vue-docs link and for the example as well!

AFAIK one should also emit the update event from the child in order to propagate the update to the parent, i.e. to allow the sync to work from child to the parent (it is not a part of your example - it is synced only from parent to child) - is this correct?

Comment: yes, you're right. Child has to call `$emit("update:active", someValue)`.